# Storing large files on Google Cloud Source Repositories

Tags: git, google-cloud-source-repos

So the background story is this:

I have some large (text) files (~100MB) that I want to version track as well as scripts that analyze them. The total amount of data I'm going to store is approximately 5GB, and I don't expect them to change as frequently as the scripts do.

I'm currently using Github, which is kind of expensive given that LFS only provides 1GB free space, whereas the similar Google Cloud service—Google Count Source Repositories (GCSR)—provides a free tier with higher storage quota.

But when I tried to migrate from Github to GCSR, I got the following error

```sh
$ git push --set-upstream google my_branch

batch response: Repository or object not found: https://console.cloud.google.com/m/clouddev/redirect/<PROJECT_NAME>:<REMOTE_REPO_NAME>.git/info/lfs/objects/batch
Check that it exists and that you have proper access to it
Uploading LFS objects:   0% (0/100), 0 B | 0 B/s, done
batch response: Repository or object not found: https://console.cloud.google.com/m/clouddev/redirect/<PROJECT_NAME>:<REMOTE_REPO_NAME>.git/info/lfs/objects/batch
Check that it exists and that you have proper access to it
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://source.developers.google.com/p/<PROJECT_NAME>/r/<REMOTE_REPO_NAME>'
```

So my question is:

- is it possible to not use LFS using GCSR?
- is there any GCSR-equivalent for LFS stored objects?
- or should I simply treat the text files are regular files (e.g. scripts) and let `git` handle it?
- or am I using the wrong tool all together?

Thanks!

Comment: I think that you should take a look at [this](https://cloud.google.com/source-repositories/docs/mirroring-a-github-repository) documentation on how to Mirror a GitHub repository.

Answer (score 0):

In the Google Issuetracker one Google employee comments on an issue about Git-lfs and Cloud source repositories:

> If you mean to transfer large files using specifically Git LFS, this is not
> supported in CSR.

In other words it's not supported unfortunately.

SOURCE: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/156228313#comment7